# How to subset a dataframe by factor levels of another in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have two daframes (A,B) that both contain exactly the same columns.

```
A<-data.frame(factor=c("A","B","C"),value=c(1,2,3))
B<-data.frame(factor=c("A","B","C","D","E"),value=c(7,8,9,4,5))
```

At the end I would like to have a subset of `B` which only contains the levels of `A$factor` (A,B,C) and the corresponding values. Any idea on how to do this?
I looked at the `merge()` function but could not get it it to work.

Comment: Be aware that the `levels` of a factor are *not* the same as the uniue value of the factor.   In other words a factor could have levels which are not represented in the values.  For example: `X <- factor(c("male", "male"), levels=c("female", "male"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative solution might be:

```
B[B$factor%in%A$factor,]
```